# How to work with MeteorPad? (Update: works at home not at work -- firewall, proxy issue?)

Tags: javascript, meteor

UPDATE:

Perhaps a firewall or proxy issue?  Wouldn't work at work, but works here at home

---

I have been trying to work with MeteorPad (http://meteorpad.com/) but can't seem to get very far with it.   The area at the bottom of the screen displays Macintosh spinning cursor — the area to the right (where I assume the app would run) simply remains blank, no matter which of the available buttons I click on.  Tried it in Chrome and Safari, Mac OS Mavericks.  Am I missing something super-obvious?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

looks like a firewall or proxy issue. I have the same problem in some networks where some ports are closed. I also have to use a http/https proxy there to access the web. I would say because some ports are closed meteor cant work because you have the whole or partial db on client.